# Write a Java Program with an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am not asking for the whole answer. I am just confused on how to start and which kind of loop I should use for the index.

Define a list of 10 int values and use a loop to print all the values based on their index. 
Program code defined an array with these ten integer values:  91, 94, 88, 85, 96, 100, 78, 91, 100, 98

Example Ouput:

The numbers in my array:

Index 0: 91
Index 1: 94
Index 2: 88
Index 3: 85
Index 4: 96
Index 5: 100
Index 6: 78
Index 7: 91
Index 8: 100
Index 9: 98

Comment: This link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: you can use either for loop or while loop,but i will recommend you to use for loop as it will be easy to use to use the loop variable to print index.

Comment: Thanks. I will try what you all suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arraySample[] = { 91, 94, 88, 85, 96, 100, 78, 91, 100, 98 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySample.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Index " + i + " : " + arraySample[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code :). I looked at the website link you posted and it helped me understand better.